# partitions deleted, cannot boot uefi

Tags: uefi

I had Windows 8 installed and dual booted with Ubuntu 14.04 enabled fast boot.
I deleted the Ubuntu and Windows partitions, because I needed space. I expected to be able to boot Windows from USB and repair from there.

I cannot boot from USB, nor access the UEFI. I press F2, but it always goes into the black screen.

Is there any way I can make usb boot the windows directly or something? Since it's a laptop, I'll lose my warranty if I open it and remove the hdd..

Comment: Can you boot _any_ USB drive? Have you tried Ubuntu Live?

Comment: I suggest you ask about this on a computer-specific forum, since this sounds like a problem with your computer's firmware, not with Ubuntu per se. (Although it could be that the computer is booting into GRUB and hanging there; it's not clear what "the black screen" you mention is. Even if this is happening, it *should* be possible to skip past GRUB by using the computer's built-in boot manager.) Unfortunately, details of how to enter and use EFI boot managers and firmware setup utilities vary greatly from one computer to another.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me how deleting both operating systems would break the BIOS.  I presume you are saying that when starting up the laptop, F2 gives you a blank screen and not the BIOS / EUFI menu.

Assuming the obvious and that F2 does indeed cause entering the BIOS on your hardware and that you have pushed F2 a LOT during the powerup phase, probably the quickest way to move this problem forward would be to reset the BIOS to factory defaults if that feature is available on your laptop.  Or, install the latest supported BIOS via the vendor's flash procedure. Needless to say, this assumes that the monitor is working and will display SOMETHING.  I'm skeptical  because what you did should have gotten you as far as a no bootable operating system found error message. It could be that the screen just coincidentally quit working for whatever reasons.

That said, since you deleted both operating system partitions you will most likely have to re-install both from scratch.